# How can I be informed before my application is killed?

Tags: qt

I want to be informed when my application is killed and to be able to deal with it.

I don't want to reimplement `QWidget::closeEvent()` or respond to the `signal` `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()`, I'm more interested in knowing when my app is terminated externally and to be informed so I can stop it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be told when the OS attempts to kill your app's process?

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975655/clean-up-before-closing-the-qcoreapplication