# Graceful termination of Qt application by unix signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals, terminate

I have problems saving settings in my application. This is done in the destructors of the relevant objects. It is a launcher and a termination by shutdown is a standard case. The only way the application actually saves the setting is by manual closing it or session shutdown (on cinnamon at least, I guess this just closes all windows). Even `sudo reboot` prevents the Qt application from unwinding the objects on the stack. Terminating by `killall -s <signal> <app>` has the same effect for `SIGINT`, `SIGKILL` and `SIGTERM`. How can I force my qt app to gracefully terminate at on `SIGTERM`? [aboutToQuit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) is not emitted either.

Comment: What you want is to trap the SIGTERM signal in your process and handle it accordingly. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942034/simple-linux-signal-handling).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/975736/1122645

Comment: Thank you, these links contained the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a minimal set of functions a unix signal handler is allowed to call. They are called *async-signal-safe* functions. Calling everything else, including every Qt function, results in undefined behavior.

Still there is a way to handle unix signals in Qt. The way uses the *self-pipe-trick* and is described in the Qt docs article ["Calling Qt Functions From Unix Signal Handlers"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html).

Basically you open a pipe and whenever you get a signal you `::write(...)`  (this is a async-signal-safe function) to the pipe. On the other end you listen to the pipe using a [QSocketNotifier](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html). For the implementation details check the Qt article mentioned above.