root process cannot receive quit signal when user session is closed in linux
I'm writing a Qt application which needs to save its data when the user session is closed. I found that if I ran it as the session owner(normal user without root privilege), QCoreApplication::quit would be called when the session closed, and if I connect QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit to some callback function, the callback will also be called. However, when I ran it as root, none of above happened when I exited the session, making my app unable to save its data.
Why this happens and what can I do to solve it? Thanks in advance.
System Info:
Operating System: Arch Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 6.2.2
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.7.0
Qt Version: 6.8.0
Kernel Version: 6.11.6-arch1-1 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11

AFAIK, UI programs may not be always made aware if the session is being closed, if the program is run from a different user than the one using the session. In fact, some linux desktop managers may just shut down the graphics server abruptly (simply because they do not have any concept of "session"), or the program may not be aware of an existing session, even if it exists: you shall never rely too much on that. That said, maybe have a look at QSessionManager related signals of QGuiApplication: saveStateRequest() and commitDataRequest().

I strongly suggest you to be really aware about the above. Unless you have absolute control/certainty about the environment in which the program is run, you can never assume that program might be aware of any session, to do anything relevant. If you're dealing with usage-changing configuration based on QSettings, consider periodically calling its sync() (the docs say it's done "at regular intervals" if the event loop is running, but doesn't clarify its frequency, and I never found out other references in the sources). If the issue is about sensitive data, consider an auto-backup system.

Thanks for help, I decided to save file every time the user change the app's settings.

Also see related posts, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/33083038 In any case, as already said, if you're just dealing with program settings, saving them whenever they're changed should be the proper choice to begin with, especially if you are aware that the program may be run with different user permissions.

I tried registering SIGTERM and SIGINT with signal(), they worked when I killed my app with signal 2 and 15, but didn't work when the session shutdown. So I think the only solution is to always save the app's settings.
